# .NET Core to Change Date-format at multiple places

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, .net-core

I have.NetCore web application.

i have used `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` at multiple places.

I want to apply different DateTime formats `("MM/dd/yyyy")` across the applications.

Is it possible to apply default format to `("MM/dd/yyyy")` across the application even if `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`
has been written in multiple places.

Comment: this is a valuable lesson on why one should not use magic strings.

Comment: Write an extension method for this and use that only

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a format, you can't bypass this format.
The answer is "No".